# Detect what has been selected on a Listbox DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a Listbox which is bonded to a list of an object that holds two elements : a string and an image

I want to detect if the user taps on the image or on the textblock

This is what I tried :

this is my xaml :

```
<ListBox x:name = "TheList"  ItemSource ="{Binding List}" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged_1">
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Name}" />
        <Image ImageSource = "{Binding Picture}" />
        <StackPanel>
        <\StackPanel>
    <\DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And here is my code behind :

```
private void SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TheList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        if(e.OriginalSource == sender as  TextBox ){
             MessageBox.Show("Text");

        }  else if(e.OriginalSource  == sender as Image ){

            MessageBox.Show("Image");

        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work if i tap on the image  the  MessageBox shows "Text"

How can I detect if the image or the textblock has been tapped?

Comment: `sender` is going to be the `ListBoxItem`, I think.  Try `if (e.OriginalSource is TextBlock)`, etc.

Comment: No it is not working and now it is not detecting neither the textblock or the image

Comment: You're right, sorry - it looks like the original source gets swallowed up by the SelectionChanged event.  You might want to consider adding a `Tap` event separately on the `Image` and `TextBlock`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have finally found my answer :

I had to add this line :

```
var myTappedobject = (Sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyObject
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
<ListBox x:name = "TheList"  ItemSource ="{Binding List}" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged_1">
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Click=hTClick" Text = "{Binding Name}" />
    <Image Click="hIClick" ImageSource = "{Binding Picture}" />
    <StackPanel>
    <\StackPanel>
<\DataTemplate>
```

In code behind:

```
private void hTClick(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("text");
}
private void hIClick(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("image");
}
```

This will show you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can not achive on SelectionChanged event of ListBox Control. but You can do it in this way

```
<ListBox x:name = "TheList"  ItemSource ="{Binding List}" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged_1">
   <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Name}" Tap="txtBlock_Tap" />
      <Image ImageSource = "{Binding Picture}" Tap="img_Tap"/>
      <StackPanel>
       <\StackPanel>
    <\DataTemplate>
</ListBox>

 private void txtBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("TextBlock click");
      var item = TheList.SelectedItem as your Type;
     }

 private void img_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("Image click");
       var item = TheList.SelectedItem as your Type;
     }
```